# Can I shorten the code with a loop solution?

Tags: excel, vba

In the end I have 15 ranges that this will be applied to. This is a snip of the code as it's redundant really. This is what I currently have and just wondering if there is a cleaner way with a for loop to do this.

```
Sub Select_Cells()
Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range, rg3 As Range
If [B7] > "" Then Set rg1 = [A1] Else Set rg1 = Nothing
If [B8] > "" Then Set rg2 = [B2] Else Set rg2 = Nothing
If [B9] > "" Then Set rg3 = [C3] Else Set rg3 = Nothing
union(rg1, rg2, rg3).Select
End Sub
```

What I was hoping to do was something like this (yes I know the construction is wrong):

```
rg1 = "[A1]": rg2 = "[B2]": rg3 = "[C3]"
r = 7
For x = 1 To 15
If Range("B" & r) > "" Then Set rg(x) = rg(x) Else Set rg(x) = Nothing
r=r+1
Next x
union(rg1, rg2, rg3).Select
```

Any help would be most appreciative.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Because you are saving individual cells into variables, looks like you may benefit from arrays. There are millions of examples about VBA and arrays

Comment: Is there any reason your end result is to select these cells? Also, are all these 15 cells below one another? Are you looking to find the first empty cell perhaps? We can help you with this code but it looks like this is not going to be the end of it, right?

Comment: @JvdV Sorry I thought it was clear. Cells B7 to B21 may or may not contain a value (unimportant as to what the value is). When each cell in B7:21 is looked at, if it is not blank, then there is a corresponding cell associated with it that needs to be selected. (will be copied, but it's the same difference - I'm good with adding a new WB/pasting to it. That's not any part of the question).

I'll use x just for all intent and purpose. If B7="X" then set range rg1 which is cell A1. B8=x,rg2 B2, etc etc etc

Comment: The answer to your question, *Can I shorten the code with a loop solution*, is "Yes."  I would hesitate to just go shorter rather than make a more robust code using loops, because shorter isn't always better.   You're looping over fifteen cells in a contiguous range, or wanting to loop through a fifteen non-contiguous ranges of cells?  The prior is a loop similar to what you've written and the latter would be the same thing inside a nested loop which loops through the fifteen separate ranges.

Comment: @Cyril I do know that shortcuts may end up causing more issues in the end so yes I agree with your statement. But I think maybe I did not explain it enough in the desired section. Oh and some are contiguous and some are non. It really does not matter as the union function handles that. And yes I do have a function to ignore Nothing values.
So really, I'm not opposed to either method. I'm versed in VBA to a point but never dealt with something like this and just trying to understand the "how" to make it happen. 
I've tried many google searches but absolute 0 results for my specific issue.

Comment: The problem you might be facing is that you cannot write `Nothing` to a union range so you might consider using a data structure (array, collection, dictionary...) to hold the cells (range objects). When you say *I have 15 ranges*, are you referring to the 15 cells you're processing, or are there 15 different ranges you need to process? Could you share the bigger picture i.e. what you are trying to do with those cells (ranges) and why you are trying to combine (collect) them? This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

### Combine Cells Into a Range

- This will check if cell `B7` in `Sheet2`. If it is not blank, it will combine cell `A1` in `Sheet1` into a range union(`durg`). Then it will do the same for the cell below `B7` which is cell `B8` in `Sheet2`,  and the cell below and to the right of cell `A1` which is cell `B2` in the worksheet `Sheet1`. It will do this 15 times altogether (another 13 times) ending with `B21` in `Sheet2` and `O15` in `Sheet1`. Finally, it will select the combined cells (in `Sheet1`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RefDiagonalUnionTEST()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Column
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim cfCell As Range: Set cfCell = cws.Range("B7")
    
    ' Diagonal
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    ' Diagonal Union of Column Non-Blanks
    Dim durg As Range: Set durg = RefDiagonalUnion(cfCell, dfCell, 15)
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No non-blank cells found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    wb.Activate
    dws.Select
    durg.Select

    MsgBox "The selected cells are" & vbLf & durg.Address(0, 0), vbInformation
    
End Sub

Function RefDiagonalUnion( _
    ByVal ColumnFirstCell As Range, _
    ByVal DiagonalFirstCell As Range, _
    ByVal rgSize As Long) _
As Range
    
    Dim cfCell As Range: Set cfCell = ColumnFirstCell
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = DiagonalFirstCell
    
    Dim durg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    Do
        If Len(CStr(cfCell.Value)) > 0 Then
            If durg Is Nothing Then
                Set durg = dfCell
            Else
                Set durg = Union(durg, dfCell)
            End If
        End If
        Set cfCell = cfCell.Offset(1)
        Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1, 1)
        n = n + 1
    Loop Until n = rgSize
    
    If durg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Set RefDiagonalUnion = durg
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to be able to effectively use looping, you need to determine regularities between the objects you're going to process.

Based on the snippets you provided, I assumed those regularities are:

- The `If` cells are adjacent to each other in vertical direction;
- The cells being selected are adjacent in diagonal direction and their row numbers equal to their column numbers (`Cells(i, i)`).

Secondly, you don't need any arrays for your task (`rg(x)` in your code is an array, I assume). You can just use a `Union` object (which is a `Range`) and update it each time `If` condition is met.

```
Dim sel As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
r = 7
For i = 1 To 15
  If Range("B" & r).Value > "" Then
    If sel Is Nothing Then
      Set sel = Cells(i, i)
    Else
      Set sel = Union(sel, Cells(i, i))
    End If
  End If
  r = r + 1
Next i
sel.Select
```

Comment: thank you but this is not quite right. The pattern you saw was just an example. They could be absolutely anywhere and are either contiguous or non-contiguous depends what cells in B7-B26 have values

Comment: @RJM, in this case, you can put cell objects or names into an array and traverse that array in a loop: `arr = Array("B7", "B10", "B13")`.